# AWS SSH and RDS permission denied - public key

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ssh, rds

I'm trying to `SSH` and connect to my RDS instance. Neither are working, giving the same error:

> Permission denied (publickey).

I've set up my credentials in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host clg-api-staging
     HostName ec2-11-111-11-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com   
     User ec2-user
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/clg-api-staging.pem
```

I've tried:

- Changing my permissions on the `pem` file: `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/clg-api-staging.pem`
- Changing my permissions on `~/.ssh/` to `700`
- Set up inbound rules for TCP on port `22` and MYSQL on port `3306`:

[image]

This is the message when I try to log in thru the profile:

```
$ ssh -v clg-api-staging

OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/danniu/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/danniu/.ssh/config line 26: Applying options for clg-api-staging
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to ec2-34-196-57-20.compute-1.amazonaws.com [34.196.57.20] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/danniu/.ssh/clg-api-staging.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/danniu/.ssh/clg-api-staging.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-34-196-57-20.compute-1.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:pATHD/i/BUstt1K3QKzJB4kNJyIQJUoFNpmpsot/5Lg
debug1: Host 'ec2-34-196-57-20.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/danniu/.ssh/known_hosts:24
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /Users/danniu/.ssh/id_dsa - not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/danniu/.ssh/github_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/danniu/.ssh/clg-api-staging.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

This is the message when attempting to connect to the RDS DB via Sequel PRO:

```
Used command:  /usr/bin/ssh -v -N -S none -o ControlMaster=no -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=3 -i /Users/danniu/.ssh/clg-api-staging.pem -o TCPKeepAlive=no -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ServerAliveCountMax=1 ec2-user@ec2-34-196-57-20.compute-1.amazonaws.com -L 55318:aa1tgl9qfl015rk.cuqlyug9ccbu.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306

OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/danniu/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Control socket " none" does not exist
debug1: Connecting to ec2-34-196-57-20.compute-1.amazonaws.com [34.196.57.20] port 22.
debug1: fd 8 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/danniu/.ssh/clg-api-staging.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/danniu/.ssh/clg-api-staging.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-34-196-57-20.compute-1.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:pATHD/i/BUstt1K3QKzJB4kNJyIQJUoFNpmpsot/5Lg
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: Device not configured
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 501
Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-34-196-57-20.compute-1.amazonaws.com,34.196.57.20' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /Users/danniu/.ssh/id_dsa - not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/danniu/.ssh/github_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/danniu/.ssh/clg-api-staging.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: See if this link helps: https://medium.com/@michalisantoniou6/connect-to-an-aws-rds-using-an-ssh-tunnel-22f3bd597924

Comment: The key is rejected by the server. Without the server logs it is impossible to guess the reason.

Comment: You need to set up a MySQL connection over SSH. I do that using a restricted access instance inside the same VPC as the RDS for security reasons. Once you have that established you can use mysql from the terminal or you can set up a GUI (such as MySQL workbench if you are using linux locally) if desired/required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly you cannot access the AWS RDS instance through SSH.
You can access it through MySQL Client.

1. Install `apt-get install MySQL-server -y`
2. Run `MySQL -h clg-api-staging -P password -p`

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to connect to RDS using SSH, that is never going to work. RDS is a database service that only allows SQL connections and not direct SSH or other administrator type access.